# Putting limits *underneath* new operators

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, math-operators

I'd like to declare a new math operator called the "strong limit" as follows:

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\slim}{s-lim}
```

So it's just "lim" (i.e., `\lim`), but with an "s-" in front. I want to be able to write things like `\slim_{t\to \pm \infty}`. And I can, and it compiles. However, it always puts the limit out to the right-hand side, never directly underneath the "s-lim" -- even when I try to use the `\limits_{...}` option. Is there any way to correct this?

Answer (score 16):

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\slim}{s-lim}
```

This will put limits underneath in display math mode (not in text mode, but will obey to `\limits`).

Comment: Incredible...that worked like a CHARM...thanks so much!

What exactly does putting the asterisk there *do* BTW?

Comment: Many LaTeX commands have a *-form that does slightly different things; in this case the command tells that the operator name should allow limits above and below in display math mode.